# Issue with creating choropleth map on Python

Tags: python, keyerror, folium, choropleth

I'm trying to create a choropleth map using folium on python and I was able to get the base map running, but when I try to add a layer with neighborhood boundaries, it does not show up on the html page. I thought maybe I had to increase the line opacity, but that doesn't seem to be it.

This is my code:

```
import folium
    import pandas as pd
    
    crimeData = pd.read_csv('NYC_crime.csv')
    crime2020 = crimeData[crimeData.CMPLNT_FR_DT == 2020]
    
    nycMap = folium.Map(location=[40.693943, -73.985880],zoom_start = 10)
    mapLines = 'nbhdMap.geojson.json'
    
    folium.Choropleth(geo_data = mapLines,
                      data = crime2020,
                      fill_color = 'OrRd',
                      fill_opacity=0.5,
                      line_opacity=1.0,
                      key_on = 'feature.geometry.coordinates',
                      columns = ['Lat_Lon']
                      )
    
    nycMap.save(outfile='index.html')
```

I'm also having trouble filling the map with data. I'm trying to make it so that each complaint documented on the CSV file from 2020 is used to show which areas received the most calls. But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kenia/Desktop/CSCI233/PRAC.py", line 10, in <module>
    folium.Choropleth(geo_data = mapLines,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/folium/features.py", line 1158, in __init__
    color_data = data.set_index(columns[0])[columns[1]].to_dict()
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is the neighborhood boundaries: https://data.beta.nyc/dataset/pediacities-nyc-neighborhoods/resource/35dd04fb-81b3-479b-a074-a27a37888ce7

And this is my data: https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Public-Safety/NYPD-Complaint-Data-Current-Year-To-Date-/5uac-w243

---

[EDIT] So I tried @r-beginners suggestion with a simpler dataset: https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Health/Restaurants-rolled-up-/59dk-tdhz

```
import pandas as pd
import folium 

data = pd.read_csv('nycrestaurants.csv')
data = pd.concat([data, str(data['ZIPCODE']).split(',')], axis=1)
data.columns = ['CAMIS', 'DBA', 'BORO', 'BUILDING', 'STREET', 'ZIPCODE']
resData = data.groupby(['ZIPCODE'])['DBA'].sum().reset_index()


nycMap = folium.Map(location=[40.693943, -73.985880],zoom_start = 10)
mapLines = 'zipMap.geojson.json'

folium.Choropleth(geo_data = mapLines,
                  data = resData,
                  key_on = 'feature.properties.postalCode',
                  columns = ['ZIPCODE', 'DBA'],
                  fill_color = 'OrRd',
                  fill_opacity=0.5,
                  line_opacity=1.0
                  ).add_to(nycMap)

nycMap.save(outfile='index.html')
```

But now I'm getting this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kenia/Desktop/CSCI233/PRAC.py", line 5, in <module>
    data = pd.concat([data, str(data['ZIPCODE']).split(',')], axis=1)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py", line 274, in concat
    op = _Concatenator(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py", line 359, in __init__
    raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'list'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
```

Comment: The reason for the error is that the 'DBA' column is a string, so it cannot be summed.

Comment: Suppose we count the number of DBAs (`.count()`) and now we need a `postalCode` on the JSON file side.

Comment: Where is the data in 'zipMap.geojosn.json'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you were presented with the data of the complaint in another question, you got the GEOJSON data from [here](https://jsspina.carto.com/tables/nyc_zip_code_tabulation_areas_polygons/public/map) for the corresponding zip code range. As for the process, we have tabulated it by the number of zip codes and tied it to the number of occurrences.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('./data/311_Noise_Complaints.csv', sep=',')
df['Incident Zip'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
df['Incident Zip'] = df['Incident Zip'].astype(int)
df_zip = df['Incident Zip'].value_counts().to_frame().reset_index()
df_zip.columns = ['postal_code', 'counts']
df_zip['postal_code'] = df_zip['postal_code'].astype(str)

import folium

nycMap = folium.Map(location=[40.693943, -73.985880], zoom_start=10)
mapLines = './data/nyc_zip_code_tabulation_areas_polygons.geojson'

choropleth = folium.Choropleth(geo_data = mapLines,
                  data = df_zip,
                  columns = ['postal_code', 'counts'],
                  key_on = 'feature.properties.postalcode',
                  fill_color = 'BuPu',
                  fill_opacity=0.5,
                  line_opacity=1.0
                  ).add_to(nycMap)

choropleth.geojson.add_child(
    folium.features.GeoJsonTooltip(['po_name'], labels=False)
)

nycMap.save(outfile='index.html')
nycMap
```

[image]

Comment: @ r-beginners I tried it with the new lines of code you suggested, but I kept getting Type Errors. I edited my original post to show my code with a more simple dataset.

Comment: Since you provided the data for the complaint in another question, I looked for the GEOJSON file for the zip code and updated all the answers. Please check the content.

Comment: Thank you so much!! For the code and taking the time to review both of my questions. I'll have to go over the code/each function to fully understand how and why it works. Now, if I can be greedy, do you mind helping me with one more thing? I'm trying to add popup texts to each area using `PO_NAME` column from GeoJson file but I keep getting a TypeError even when I change the datatype.

Comment: This is my code: `for x in mapLines:
    mapLines['PO_NAME'] = mapLines['PO_NAME'].astype(int)
    nbhd = mapLines['PO_NAME']
    mapLines.add_child(folium.Popup(nbhd))
    mapLines.add_to(nycMap)`   and this is the error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kenia/Desktop/CSCI233/PRAC.py", line 20, in <module>
    mapLines['PO_NAME'] = mapLines['PO_NAME'].astype(int)
TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: Sorry for the weird spacing^

Comment: Tooltips are cooler than pop-ups. Updated code. I used [this page](https://towardsdatascience.com/using-folium-to-generate-choropleth-map-with-customised-tooltips-12e4cec42af2) as a reference.